# Ansible rolling upgrade - how to test server response with timeout?

Tags: ansible, devops

I have 2 servers hosting a website.
I want to do a rolling upgrade with Ansible like the following:

1. upgrade one server at a time
2. take the building node off the load balancer
3. run the task, restart server
4. waiting for the server to start up, send a request to a test URL every 5 seconds until a valid response is received,  it will timeout after 3 minutes and the ansible playbook fails.
5. If the build was successful, build the next node until all finishes.

Of the above, 1,2,3,5 can be done with Ansible by default. But I can't find any documentation on how to achieve step 4 with Ansible without writing a custom script.

Any pointer will be appreciated.

UPDATE

I finally got it working with `wait_for` and `until`:

```
 - name: "wait for port to be available"
    wait_for:
      host: "127.0.0.1"
      port: "{{port}}"
      timeout: 30
  - name: "wait for web app to start up"
    shell: curl -XGET --head --silent http://127.0.0.1:{{port}}/test
    register: result
    until: result.stdout.find("200 OK") != -1
    retries: 60
    delay: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`wait_for`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/wait_for_module.html) module:

```
- wait_for:
    host: path.to.the.node
    port: 80
    connect_timeout: 5
    timeout: 180
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,  wait_for only waits for the port to be available but it does not gurantee the website returns a 200 response. When the website is starting up, the port is usually already available but requests to the website return 503

Comment: You can add the `search_regex` parameter and check for the expected response.

Answer (score 0):

ping the page with [uri](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/uri_module.html)

There is a timeout argument there.

example:

```
- name: wait for nginx
  wait_for:
    port: 443

- name: wait for test page
  uri:
    url: https://test/page
    timeout: '{{ 3 * 60 }}'
```